# Como detectar o encoding da página com PHP?

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres

Queria criar uma função que salvasse os dados no banco sempre no *encoding* correto (meu banco é UTF-8) de acordo com o *encoding* detectado.

Existe alguma função nativa do PHP pra fazer isso? Há alguma outra forma?

Comment: O que você está tentando salvar? Dados fornecidos pelo usuário? Arquivos no próprio servidor? E qual o formato desses dados? (o título da pergunta sugere páginas html, é isso mesmo?)

Comment: Sim dados fornecidos por um usuário. Os arquivos são .php utilizado com html. Como assim o formato dos dados?

Comment: Perguntei do formato porque em alguns casos (ex.: HTML/XML) essa informação pode estar contida no próprio documento (ex.: `meta http-equiv="Content-Type"`), podendo ser extraída do mesmo. Em outros, o que resta é "adivinhar" (usando o `mb_detect_encoding`). Veja a resposta do @Guerra. Só que, pessoalmente, considero má prática trabalhar com encodings desconhecidos, por isso quero entender melhor seu problema para sugerir uma solução mais apropriada.

Comment: Novamente o problema de conscientizar programadores a usarem UTF8 e de conseguirmos fazer isso a contento no PHP: [ver essa resposta para mais detalhes](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8641/4186)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assumindo que seu servidor está servindo páginas codificadas como `UTF-8`, o comportamento padrão da maioria dos agentes de usuário (*browsers* etc) será utilizar essa mesma codificação ao enviar dados de volta ao servidor (através de formulários/POST, por exemplo). Também é possível aceitar outras codificações através do parâmetro [`accept-charset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accept-charset). Dessa forma não será necessário "detectar" nada, você próprio está instruindo o lado cliente a enviar dados já na codificação desejada.

Veja também [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3237887/520779) no SO em inglês. Um dos pontos importantes é que um *browser* **que segue os padrões** vai respeitar essa exigência de *encoding*, mas sempre é possível que um cliente (acidentalmente ou maliciosamente) envie dados com codificação diferente. Nesse caso, cabe a você determinar se é necessário tentar corrigir o problema que o cliente criou, ou deixar o ônus para ele... Usuários comuns utilizando navegadores modernos certamente não passarão por esse tipo de problema (mas não custa nada realizar alguns testes, de acordo com seu público alvo).

---

**Atualização:** baseado nas respostas sua e do @Guerra, creio que não é necessário detectar coisa alguma, simplesmente usar `utf8_decode` deveria ser o suficiente (pois seus usuários enviarão sempre em UTF-8, e sua conexão ao banco sempre espera ISO 8859-1, independentemente da codificação que o seu banco usa).

Mas se você quer uma solução robusta, eis o que sugiro:

```
function fixEncoding($in_str)
{
   $cur_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($in_str) ;

   if($cur_encoding == "UTF-8" && mb_check_encoding($in_str,"UTF-8"))
   {
       return utf8_decode($in_str);
   }
   elseif($cur_encoding == "ISO 8859-1" && mb_check_encoding($in_str,"ISO 8859-1"))
   {
       return $in_str;
   }
   else
   {
       // Não testado:
       // return iconv($cur_encoding, "ISO 8859-1", $in_str);
       throw new Exception('Codificação não suportada.');
   }
}
```

Comment: Só um comentário. Essa função do PHP mb_detec_encoding detecta se a string possui caracteres ASCII ou UTF-8 e não sobre a página que foi a pergunta original. De qualquer forma já ajuda.

Answer (score 9):

A tua pergunta é um pouco vaga em relação ao problema especifico que estás a encontrar, pelo que, deixo aqui algumas considerações a ter para uma correta iteração com dados do utilizador, dados de e para o servidor e iteração com a base de dados, partindo da base indicada de que a tua base de dados está a funcionar com Charset UTF-8.

<sup>**Notas:** Isto pode não responder à tua pergunta, mas parece-me relevante o suficiente para ajudar quando lidamos com problemas de codificação. Pode ser adicionada muito mais informação. Basta indicar em comentário o pretendido.</sup>

### Declarações ao navegador

- **Páginas HTML**

  As páginas HTML precisam sempre de uma indicação no cabeçalho através de uma META tag, do charset que o navegador deve utilizar para apresentar e receber dados:

  Exemplo em HTML 5

  ```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    ...
  ```

  Exemplo em HTML 4

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    ...
  ```
- **Ficheiros PHP**

  O ficheiro principal responsável por apresentar o HTML e realizar as funções de interação com o utilizador (normalmente o index.php), deve conter uma indicação logo no início do mesmo, antes de qualquer envio de cabeçalhos para o browser, indicando o charset a utilizar:

  ```php
  /* Setting charset for proper language
   * support, DB interaction, etc.
   */
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  ```

  Isto vai garantir que a informação enviada para o navegador e a informação recolhida do mesmo vão estar em UTF-8.
- **Posts ao servidor via HTML > PHP**

  Se o PHP e o cabeçalho da página HTML estiverem a indicar o mesmo Charset, como visto em cima, um post normal a partir de um formulário na página vai enviar a informação do navegador para o servidor em UTF-8.

  Contudo, existe uma forma de indicar que o formulário deverá enviar os dados para o servidor num Charset especifico:

  ```html
  <form action="mytargetfile.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  ```

  Isto não é necessário pois o procedimento "normal" é aplicar o mencionado nos pontos em cima. Mas pode ser utilizado sem problemas.
- **Posts ao servidor via Ajax > PHP**

  Os posts realizados via Ajax enviam a informação respeitando as indicações da página HTML. Essa mesma informação deve chegar a um ficheiro de destino que tenha a indicação do charset a utilizar.

  Contudo, também aqui é possível indicar o Charset a utilizar para o envio de dados:

  ```js
  $.ajax({
    data: parameters,
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_url,
    contentType: "application/x-javascript; charset:UTF-8",
    success: callback
  });
  ```

  A indicação do tipo de conteúdo varia, naturalmente, de acordo com o conteúdo a enviar, mas a mesma é sucedida pela indicação do Charset a utilizar.

## Cuidados a ter com os ficheiros

Ao editarmos ou criarmos um ficheiro, devemos ter sempre em conta que o mesmo deve ficar codificado com o Charset igual à informação que vai passar por ele.

[image: Codificação do Ficheiro]

Isto é um pequeno detalhe, mas que garante que a informação esteja a ser bem gerida em relação à codificação da mesma.

## Iteração com a Base de Dados

Aqui é importante ter em atenção que a ligação que abrimos à base de dados para guardar ou ler dados deve estar a utilizar o mesmo Charset que os dados e o código responsável por esta operação estão a utilizar:

Exemplo de ligação à base de dados via PDO indicando o Charset:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Instances a new database connection
 * @return PDO instance of PDO connection
 */
protected function InitConnetion() {

  $dbh = new PDO(
    'mysql:host="meuServidor";dbname="minhaBD";',
    "utilizador",
    "password",
    array(
      PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT               => false,
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE                  => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND       => "SET NAMES utf8"
    )
  );

  return $dbh;
}

?>
```

Repara que estou a aplicar "utf8" ao invés de "utf-8" pois o ficheiro que a base de dados tem com as instruções deste Charset chama-se utf8. Dependendo a configuração do servidor o ficheiro pode chamar-se "utf-8", "utf8" ou "bananas". Quando indicas um nome que não existe, recebes um erro, e sabes que vais ter que alterar.

Comment: +1 Excelente resposta, em particular a parte que fala "Cuidados a ter com os ficheiros". Um erro em potencial - e com consequências bastante danosas, às vezes irreversíveis - é especificar um *encoding* nos meta-dados, mas ter o seu conteúdo num *encoding* **diferente**. Já corrompi muitos arquivos/ficheiros por conta desse erro... (felizmente apenas com arquivos pessoais, nada do trabalho ou pior: de clientes)

Answer (score 3):

A melhor forma de converter ISO 8859-1 caracter para UTF8 que encontrei foi essa:

```
function fixEncoding($in_str)
{
  $cur_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($in_str) ;
  if($cur_encoding == "UTF-8" && mb_check_encoding($in_str,"UTF-8"))
    return $in_str;
  else
    return utf8_encode($in_str);
}
```

Mas no caso de arquivos HTML basta usar esse cabeçalho:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Recomendo fortemente a leitura [desse](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) artigo(inglês) achei muito útil para entender os encoding da vida que no PHP as vezes dão no saco.

Para outros formatos o mais indicado seria o metodo `iconv` mas teria que fazer alguns testes para tentar faze-lo de forma dinâmica em relação a codificação atual ver [iconv php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Fonte: [Aqui](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php#89789)

Comment: `utf8_encode($in_str)` você tem certeza que isso funciona? A documentação que você indicou diz que o parâmetro `data` deve ser uma string ISO-8859-1. O que acontece se o encoding detectado estiver em outro formato (digamos, UTF-16) e você passar essa string para `utf8_encode`?

Comment: @mgibsonbr realmente tens razão, falha minha. Editei a resposta para futuras pesquisas.

Answer (score 1):

Baseado na resposta do @Guerra consegui achar a solução. Minha página html esta com Charset UTF-8 setado e meu Banco MySQL também. O que é estranho pois quando a função detecta o caractere como UTF-8 preciso usar o ut8_decode para que entre corretamente a acentuação no banco.

Pelo que entendo utf8_decode transformaria em ISO-8859-1, alguem pode dar uma explanação melhor nos comentários?

```
  function fixEncoding($in_str)
  {
       $cur_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($in_str) ;

       if($cur_encoding == "UTF-8" && mb_check_encoding($in_str,"UTF-8"))
       {
           return utf8_decode($in_str);
       }
       else
       {
           return $in_str;
       }
  }
```

Comment: O seu banco pode estar em `UTF-8`, mas **a biblioteca que faz interface com ele** pede parâmetros em que formato?

Comment: Como eu vejo isso?

Comment: Não sei como você descobre, mas se você citar aqui a gente pode dar uma ajuda... Mas segundo o que você relatou, suspeito fortemente que seja `ISO-8859-1`. É preciso entender a diferença entre o encoding usado pelo banco e o encoding que você usa pra fazer a conexão a ele. Se uma mesma biblioteca se conecta a 10 bancos diferentes, cada um com um encoding diferente, ainda assim o SQL que você vai passar pra ela vai sempre usar o mesmo encoding. É função do BD usar o encoding certo, a sua função é interagir com a biblioteca que faz a conexão.

Comment: Eu não sei o que você chama de 'biblioteca que faz interface' para poder te falar. A collation do banco e das tabelas eu vi pelo HeidiSQL. Não entendo muito sobre encoding e está sendo muito produtivo saber mais. Obrigado pelas explicações.

Comment: Cara, eu entendo muito de encoding mas pouco de PHP... Talvez alguém mais experiente pode te ajudar mais, mas a curto prazo, se você está passando ISO-8859-1 pro seu banco e ele está aceitando, é porque é isso mesmo que ele está pedindo, então não precisa esquentar demais a cabeça com isso... :)

Comment: Valeu, obrigado. Só queria entender melhor mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

### Programadores da língua portuguesa: o nosso charset é o UTF8!

Resumidamente, esse fato, para programadores PHP, acarreta dois cuidados:

1. Páginas, dados, scripts PHP, tudo deve ser codificado em UTF8. Desconfie da arquitetura, da biblioteca, do ambiente, do que for que não estiver representando o português em em UTF-8.
2. Fique atento ao PHP, ele não é "nativamente UTF8", isso pode causar transtornos. Para superar esse problema, confira as [dicas e detalhes nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8641/4186).

---

Edit (depois comentário Bacco)

Não é uma questão de "preferência pessoal", é uma questão de *respeito*, assim como são respeitadas as placas de trânsito, independente de gostarmos delas ou não.

Respeito às seguintes convenções, *"[de jure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_jure)"* e "[de fato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto)":

- [ePING, principal recomendação brasileira para interoperabilidade-BR](http://eping.governoeletronico.gov.br/#p2s4)
- [RFC3629, IETF (Internet)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt), assim como XML, HTM5, etc. no W3C
- ... Padrão "de fato" (que um dia, quando se dava a liberdade do "cada um por si", foi da Microsoft) ver [histórico da aderência na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) ou direto [uma das fontes aqui](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/character_encoding/all). Ou seja, há uma grande aderência pelo mundo, de quase **90%**.

Comment: Nosso charset é o ISO-8859-1, que tem todos os caracteres Latinos e acentuação que usamos. É mais performático, pois usa armazenamento 1 caracter x 1 byte. UTF-8 serve basicamente para internacionalização. Com todo respeito ao Peter Krauss e suas outras idéias que eu até gosto, esta não é o caso. UTF-8 pode ter suas vantagens, mas esta não é uma delas. Aliás, se não fosse por causa de emoticons, caracteres árabes, chineses, etc, o UTF-8 só teria desvantagens. Respeito como uma opção pessoal  (independente de ruim ou boa), mas não sendo apresentado como fato absoluto.

Comment: Oi @Bacco, fiz um edit e abri para Wiki caso queira voce mesmo editar alguma incorreção... É uma confusão comum, e você está errado quando diz que ISO-9959-1 "É mais performático, pois usa armazenamento 1 caracter x 1 byte". O UTF8 é justamente  um grande sucesso e um grande consenso pois, justamente nas línguas ocidentais, que são as mais usadas na Internet,  preserva 1 byte (!!).  Esse 1 byte tem  justamente "todos os caracteres Latinos e acentuação que usamos" (o Ã por exemplo é o 195<255)... enfim, dupla confusão: ver link Wikipedia-Ingles que passei (Wikipedia português é confuso).

Comment: Não vou entrar em debate, pq ja comentei disso antes. Não sei o quanto você entende de como os encodings mencionados funcionam, mas posso dizer sem medo que UTF-8 é mais lento e complexo de se trabalhar do que o ISO-8859-1. Essa coisa de 1 byte ja é perdida na acentuação em português. Quanto aos links, são recomendações para troca de dados entre sistemas, e não uso geral. Se em algum momento quiser e coincidir seu tempo com o meu, podemos levantar essas questões num chat, ou coisa do tipo. Não se trata de eleger o "melhor", mas de entender que nenhum formato é absolutamente superior ao outro.

Answer (score -3):

No Style CSS: html:lang(pt-br) { @charset "UTF-8"; }

No HTML: html lang="pt-br"

No HEAD: meta charset="UTF-8"

Eu uso o HTML5 com PHP versão 7.3 e funciona.