# Minha página buga no charset

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres

Sem o charset utf-8, Minha página fica assim:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb0Rt.png

Buga onde tem php e onde tem html fica normal

Mas quando eu coloco

```
<?php header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
```

ou

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

A página buga o html e fica certo o php: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5fHX.png

To confuso, no phpmyadmin já tá uft8 também

Comment: Ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/636/como-detectar-o-encoding-da-página-por-php/642#642

Comment: Aparentemente você está misturando os charsets na mesma página. Ou conserta o PHP, ou conserta o HTML. Comece pondo o charset do editor de código que você usa no modo certo, para facilitar.

Comment: Se não conseguir resolver com as informações do link que eu indiquei, avise aqui, incluindo meu username com uma @ na frente para que eu seja notificado ok?